# Can a freestanding **gas** range share 15AMP circuit with a range hood/extractor?

Tags: wiring, gas, oven

I have a freestanding **gas** range in my basement suite that is not currently vented. Obviously this is a problem -- CO more than grease -- and I want to install a range hood to direct-vent outside.

The range is on a dedicated 15 amp circuit, with a 3-prong 120V plug. Can I use the same circuit to run the vent?

I would like to replace the existing 120 V outlet with a junction box and then run wiring up the stud to a new outlet for the vent, and down the stud to a second outlet for the range. This would let me address the additional problem of the range now pushing all the way back because the outlet is too high - there is a void at the bottom of the range made for gas fittings and electric clearance. The junction box will be accessible by pulling out the freestanding range.

I am in Vancouver, Canada, so building codes may differ from your area.

Comment: This is a semi-related question: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/is-it-safe-to-have-a-gas-stove-on-the-same-circuit-as-a-couple-lights. The range's literature should tell you if it requires a dedicated circuit, and your local code will probably as well. My guess is that both will tell you it should be on its own.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey The range's literature is long gone. I believe current code would require dedicated circuits but I do not know the correct way to proceed in a 100 year old house where the different renovations allow an archeological surveys of the changes in local building code. The other question has no good answer - but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: check the wattage and or the amps required by each device if they total to less than 15A then you are good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steven - I am also in Vancouver, and just installed a new kitchen with permits and inspections. Yes, the gas range and hood can be on the same 15A circuit, as mine are. Just be sure that the oven is also gas, and does not have any electric broiler or electric self-clean. If the rating is under 12A you are fine. If you are splicing into an existing 15A circuit, you can install as many junction boxes as you need, so long as they are accessible by pulling out the range, or by removing the range hood's fake pipe, or by opening the door of a cabinet above the range hood. My splice is in the receptacle box that the Ikea hood fan plugs into.

I have always had gas ranges, built-in ovens and cooktops, and have never heard of CO being a problem. It should only be a problem if the flame isn't getting enough oxygen.

In the basement, you probably have a gas furnace, gas HWT and gas dryer. They all suck air. If you add a range hood and a bathroom fan, you could be seriously short of makeup air. I was required to add a 4" fresh air vent in the new basement suite. I put it behind the fridge, so that the cold incoming air would mix with the heat from the back of the fridge, avoiding cold drafts.

Comment: Tom, thanks for your reply. My range is rated 15A but so is the entire product line. It is all gas, no electric broiler or electric self-clean, so I think the 15A is a 'vendor being safe' value. I went ahead and spliced it in and have my fingers crossed it all will be fine once gas is hooked up. If not I will fix it. As for fresh air I was required to put a fresh air vent in when the furnace was replaced so I think it should be fine. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the electrical parts of the gas range are an oven lamp, igniters and some control circuitry it will not consume any significant amount of electricity. Therefore, plugging the vent fan into the same circuit should be fine.

If you want a definitive answer you will need an ammeter. Good news is they are readily available for under $100. You do need an adapter - you can't just clamp them on a regular power cord. Adapters either come with the meter or are on the shelf right beside it.